# Replace two or more spaces to &nbsp,&nbsp

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I encode convert spaces to &nbsp in objective-c?

I need each space is replaced by &nbsp, except when only one space

Example

```
in  text: AAA    BBB C
out text: AAAnbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;BBB C
```

thanks

Comment: That isn't a question, it's an imperative. It's nicer to actually ask a question. "How do I do X?".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about NSStrings -- look at the NSString documentation. There are instance methods for replacing strings of the form `stringByReplacing...`

Comment: I need each space is replaced by &nbsp, except when only one space

Comment: @Andrey do you know what Documentation and Instance method mean?

Comment: @Andrey Yes, I know, you asked that in the question. And I replied with relevant information. You need to be willing to help yourself a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use `NSString` or `NSMutableString`:

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@"&nbsp;&nbsp;"];
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@"&nbsp;&nbsp;"];
```

Yes, this needs to be done twice for the case of an odd number of spaces in a row.

---

If you are dealing with C-strings instead of `NSString`s or `NSMutableString`s, you do the same but with a function instead of a method. I am not going to write such a function here but know that you have to run it twice. :)

Comment: You relacing two spaces to one nbsp. I want replace each space to nbsp. Please see example